# How to multiply two columns in a spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Say I am having a dataframe named "orderitems" with below schema

```
    DataFrame[order_item_id: int, order_item_order_id: int, order_item_product_id: int, order_item_quantity: int, order_item_subtotal: float, order_item_product_price: float]
```

So As a part of checking the data quality , I need to ensure all rows satisfies the formula :  *order_item_subtotal = (order_item_quantity*order_item_product_price)*. 
For this I need to add a seperate column named "valid" which should have 'Y' as value for all those rows which  satisfy the above formula and for all other rows it should have 'N' as value.
I have decided to use when() and otherwise() along with  withColumn() method as below.

```
    orderitems.withColumn("valid",when(orderitems.order_item_subtotal != (orderitems.order_item_product_price * orderitems.order_item_quantity),'N').otherwise("Y"))
```

But it returns me below Error:

```
    TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

I know this happened because I have tried to multiply two column objects. But I am not sure how to resolve this since I am still on a learnig proccess in spark.
I would like to know , how to fix this. I am using Spark 2.3.0 with Python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,when
orderitems.withColumn("valid",
          when(col("order_item_subtotal") != (col("order_item_product_price") * col("order_item_quantity")),"N")
          .otherwise("Y")).show()
```

Comment: I have corrected the typo. But this approach is not working for me. I am using Spark 2.3.0 with Python. "=!=" is throwing me "invalid syntax"

Comment: @akhilpathirippilly `=!=` is Scala thing, `!=` is fine in Python

Comment: Its working :). And surprisingly the above code which I have mentioned in problem statement also working. I am not sure what made it to throw error previously. Any way thanks for your time to look into this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This can be implemented through spark UDF functions which are very efficient in performing row operartions.
Before running this code make sure the comparison you are doing should have the same datatype.

```
def check(subtotal, item_quantity, item_product_price):
  if subtotal == (item_quantity * item_product_price):
    return "Y"
  else:
    return "N"

validate = udf(check)

orderitems = orderitems.withColumn("valid", validate("order_item_subtotal", "order_item_quantity", "order_item_product_price"))
```

Comment: udf is less efficient in large datasets.